# NetworkUtils class

Tags: android, networking

I want to import NetworkUtils. Following command does not work.

```
 import android.net.NetworkUtils;
```

Other classes like WifiInfo can be imported.

Somewhere, I found it answered that NetworkUtils was not part of Android SDK and so, an SDK project cannot perform the import.

But is there a way to import android.net.NetworkUtils?

Comment: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.1_r1/android/net/NetworkUtils.java.

Answer (score 2):

The class is not part of the SDK, this may be improved in future SDK releases : https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/android-developers/9Ux2zCqCMOA

Comment: http://grepcode.com/search?query=android.net&start=0&entity=type&n=. Check the link. I think Snicolas is right.