# Sending DNS query to a domain in Android

Tags: android, sockets, dns, datagram

I am trying to send a DNS query message to let's say www.google.com to get A record of DNS. I read [this](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd197470(v=ws.10).aspx) article to find out the structure of DNS query.

I created the buffer message as:

```
 private static final byte[] RequestPacket = {

            // Transaction ID: 0x0000
            0x00, 0x00,

            // Flags: 0x0000 (Standard query)
            0x00, 0x00,

            // Questions: 1
            0x00, 0x01,

            // Answer RRs: 0
            0x00, 0x00,

            // Authority RRs: 0
            0x00, 0x00,

            // Additional RRs: 0
            0x00, 0x00,

            // Queries
            // Name: www.google.com
            0x03, 0x77, 0x77, 0x77, 0x06, 0x67, 0x6F, 0x6F, 0x67, 0x6C, 0x65, 0x03, 0x63,
            0x6F, 0x6D, 0x00,

            // Type: A Record
            0x00, 0x01

    };
```

That's how I am creating send, receive packets and my socket as well:

```
DatagramPacket sendPacket = new DatagramPacket(RequestPacket , RequestPacket .length, InetAddress.getByName("www.google.com"), 9876);
DatagramPacket recievePacket = new DatagramPacket(mBuffer, mBuffer.length);
DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket();
```

I am not able to receive any response back(`SocketTimeoutException`) when I call `socket.receive(recievePacket);` after sending the packet

I think I am messing up with the port of my send packet, but after searching google for a lot of time that's the port I found to query for DNS.

Can somebody tell me what exactly am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`InetAddress.getByName()` performs a DNS query for you and returns an IP address of the specified host (the host may have multiple IP addresses, if you need them all then use `getAllByName()` instead).

In your example, `getByName("www.google.com")` returns an IP address for Google's HTTP server, **NOT** a DNS server.  You cannot send DNS queries to an HTTP server.  This is why you are not getting a response back.

If you really want to send your own DNS queries, you need to direct them to a real DNS server, like the one provided by your Wifi/Cellular network provider (see [How do you get the current DNS servers for Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3070144/)), or a third-party DNS server (like [Google's Public DNS](https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/)).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Actually, I need more than just A field when I query for a domain that's why InetAddress is not enough. Also, I changed address to google DNS server(8.8.8.8)  and it seemed to work. Note that I had to add IN type in RequestPacket at the end as well to make it work.

Comment: I know this is an old question but what's the purpose of sending your own DNS query instead of a random byte array?