# dnsjava returns network error on lookup.run()

Tags: android, kotlin, dnsjava

I'm using dnsjava in my android app to retrieve a txt file on the first time the app starts up.

```
val lookup = Lookup(domain, Type.TXT)

lookup.setResolver(SimpleResolver())

val records = lookup.run()
if (lookup.result == Lookup.SUCCESSFUL)
       //Do things
```

I'm not able to do the retrieval and doing some debugging I find that after doing the .run(), the result on the lookup object is Lookup.Try_Again, returning a network error as the string returned when I drill into .run(). Not sure why this is occuring when the device that's being run on has perfect internet connectivity otherwise. Looking a little deeper I find that the nameserver used by the Resolver is just localhost. The url from which I'm retrieving from is public facing. How do I fix my error and what should I change the nameserver to such that this works?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're using Oreo?  Android made a change and no longer exposes dns through getprop, which is what dnsjava uses.  Alternatives can be found here: [How do you get the current DNS servers for Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3070144/how-do-you-get-the-current-dns-servers-for-android)